# Keras with TensorFlow: ... always got loss: nan when one input column all zeros

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am using `tensorflow==1.2.1` and `Keras==2.0.6` to build a model:

```
input_num = X_norm_keras[:,2:].shape[1]
model_keras = Sequential()
model_keras.add(Dense(5, input_dim=input_num, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.2)))
model_keras.add(Dense(1, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.2)))

model_keras.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',  optimizer='adam')
model_keras.fit(X_norm_train[:,2:], y_norm_train, batch_size=20, epochs=10)
```

But got the following output:

```
Epoch 1/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 2/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 3/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 4/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 5/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 6/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 7/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 8/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 9/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
Epoch 10/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: nan
```

---

Update:

I found out that the cause was due to one input column is all zero. However, I am wondering why would this become a problem in TensorFlow? In the real life, it is possible that one of the input feature in the training set are all zeros in the desired time period. Also, other algorithms such as random forest or ridge regression handle such cases fine. Why would TensorFlow failed in such case?

Comment: You are dividing by zero somewhere.

Comment: Do u mean the TensorFlow library is dividing by zero somewhere? My input just a numeric matrix ... anything I can do to prevent later dividing by zero in the later TensorFlow computation?

Comment: Actually maybe i was wrong about that. I'm not that familiar with Keras. Mostly I'm a tensorflow user.

Comment: can you provide sample of your data?

Comment: I believe there is a possibility of "relu" be causing that in a case where all its outputs are zero. As you know, relu is linear when the result is positive, and constantly zero otherwise (so, there is an actual chance that all results be zero). Maybe the regularizer is not dealing properly  with those zeros. (Try using another activation for testing). If 'relu' is essential for you, maybe you should work on weight initializers that assure at least one positive result. -- Also, if you're unlucky, your data combination with this model will tend to always reach this point.

Comment: Thanks all! I found out it caused by an all zeros column in the training set, and updated my question above. I am wondering why other algorithms (random forest, ridge regression) work fine for such case but TensorFlow failed ... Thanks!